# The requested feature is not implemented monodevelop

Tags: ado.net, monodevelop, oledb

I'm trying to debug my project in MonoDevelop. I'm using the interface ADO.net. But I keep getting folowing error:

> The requested feature is not implemented at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Dispose (Boolean disposing)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Mono's implementation of the OLE DB provider is not complete, since OLE DB is a native Windows API (Mono's implementation wraps the Linux libgda instead). I suggest you use a different ADO.NET provider.

Comment: I use sql now, but my monodevelop does not recognize entity framework (system.data.entity)

Comment: Mono does not include an Entity Framework implementation (Mono 3.x does but only for the 4.5 framework).