# Efficiently deserializing large data structures

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First off, I am new-ish to web development, but I can't find a similar question anywhere.

A web app I have been building recently uses machine learning and makes Ajax calls to the server. Whenever an Ajax call is made, my controller deserializes my training set, which is relatively small for ML, but large enough that it takes some time (25MB?).  This results in a significant amount of waiting on the client side, and can take up to 20-30 seconds to read into memory, train my Naive Bayes model and create a prediction.

My inclination is to create a `static readonly` training set object at runtime and just to hold it in memory in the Controller so that upon Ajax calls, the user only waits 2 seconds or so, but I'm not sure what kind of repercussions this could have in other areas of performance.

I am using Mono, which means I can't use `OleDB` to read in a .xlsx (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703421/the-requested-feature-is-not-implemented-monodevelop) question) and have to read a .csv to `DataTable` every call.

My question is twofold:

1. What are best practices regarding holding a large datastructure in memory in order to avoid this conundrum?
2. Is there a more efficient way to store/read this data into memory in the first place?

I'm sorry if this is common knowledge or has been answered before; please direct me to the appropriate question/answer if so.

Comment: What format is the training set and what are you doing to deserialize it? Where are you pulling the data from? Honestly, this question is so broad I don't think you'll get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The broadness of my question was my fear as well. My original attempt was deserializing from .xlsx but Mono prohibits Ole DB usage and throws a NotImplementedException. So for the moment, I've switched to reading in a CSV using Accord IO's CsvReader. Finally, the biggest question I have is whether it would be best to just store the training set in the controller? As I understand, there is not a new instance of the controller created for every user, so just storing it once should not pose (that I know of) any major issues?

Comment: Just keeping it in memory is fine and the only real drawback is eating 30 MB of ram which isnt much nowadays. Loading it may be made faster using a RDBMS or NoSQL data store instead of excel. Honestly, I think the biggest hurdle you will have is when a 30 MB dataset is in transit to/from the browser. You may be able to use some specialized data structure but we cannot tell you without seeing the data.